# Read a file and apply the operation and store it

Tags: regex, perl, hash

Say I have a file called param.txt. It contains,

```
param1 = 5;
param2 = 10;
param3 = 12;
param4 = 5;
param5 = param1 + param2;
param6 = param2 * param1;
param7 = param5 - param2;
param8 = param1 * param2 - param4;
```

I am reading this file in a perl script and storing all the parameter values till param4 in a hash.

How will I store param5,param6,param7,param8 by applying the intended operation of just by reading file and build the hash?

Answer (score 1):

Well simple way is using regex with perl code and eval:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use Data::Dumper;

my %ns = ();

while( my $line = <> )
{
    chomp($line);
    next unless ($line);

    my ($term, $expr) = split m/\s*=\s*/, $line;

    if( $term && $expr )
    {
        $expr =~ s/(\w+)/exists $ns{$1} ? $ns{$1}: $1/ge;
        $ns{$term} = eval $expr;
        warn $@ if $@;
    }
}

say Dumper(\%ns);
```

Comment: Looks pretty, but wouldn't that for example `eval {param1 + param2}` instead of `eval {$param1 + $param2}` (without the `$`s?)

Comment: regex replaces terms with their values if they were previously defined

Comment: Ah, now I see. Even prettier. Your code doesn't do `eval {param1+param2}`, but instead `eval {5+10}`. Cool.